# Как в phpmyadmin делать связь один ко многим?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, связывание-данных

Как в phpmyadmin делать связь один ко многим?
Хочу реализовать в таблице к примеру если пользователь добавит новости, то помимо прочего покажет и автора (кто добавил новость).

Answer (score 1):

Связь создается при помощи внешнего ключа ([FOREIGN KEY](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_foreign_key.html)).

Используйте SQL - этот способ не зависит от GUI.

Answer (score 0):

в табличке пользователя задайте primary key id пользователя, в табличке news добавте поле id_author например и связывайте записи по этому айдишнику. выдернуть данные о авторе можно стандартными Join запросами